# Prevent keyboard layout change on Google Translate

Tags: gboard, google-translate

**Google Translate changes my Gboard layout according to the input language.**

Might be ideal under some circumstances, but not now. Especially without consulting me first. And much more especially if it buries the option to revert it.

For instance: It changes from QUERTY to QUERTZ, when the input is in Deutch.

There is no other layout or languages selected under *Language & Input*

Good and old (and probably never upgrading) **Android 8**, if relevant.

**Google Translate V6.27.0.1** (not updating that one, by the way. Read the comments on the store to understand why)

Comment: I have the same thought of irritation. Have you found a solution yet? It's like no one gave this any thought. I guess you could always download another keyboard. Jeez what a time to be alive

Comment: I can't understand how nobody else complained about this. Not expecting a solution from google, obviously. If someone find a solution, expect it to be through XPosed

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Google Translate.
2. Press on the profile (usually on the top right), then Settings.
3. Select Keyboard, disable Automatic language selection.

[image]